# Error when configuring MySQL on EBS volume

Tags: mysql, ubuntu, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, symlink

I'm working on configuring MySQL to store its data on an Amazon EBS volume. I've mounted the volume at `/data`, moved the config and data files to the volume, and symlinked the MySQL files:

```
ln -s /data/mysql/lib/mysql /var/lib/mysql
ln -s /data/mysql/etc/mysql/my.cnf /etc/mysql/my.cnf
ln -s /data/mysql/log/mysqld.log /var/log/mysqld.log
```

The database server runs but crashes after several hours with this error:

```
130316  9:59:04  InnoDB: Database was not shut down normally! 
InnoDB: Starting crash recovery. 
InnoDB: Reading tablespace information from the .ibd files... 
130316  9:59:04  InnoDB: Operating system error number 40 in a file operation. 
InnoDB: Error number 40 means 'Too many levels of symbolic links'. 
InnoDB: Some operating system error numbers are described at 
InnoDB: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/operating-system-error-codes.html 
InnoDB: File name ./ln 
InnoDB: File operation call: 'stat'. 
InnoDB: Error: os_file_readdir_next_file() returned -1 in 
InnoDB: directory . 
InnoDB: Crash recovery may have failed for some .ibd files!
```

Does anybody understand this error and how to fix it? I've tried to find out more, but there's not much documentation. I'm running an Ubuntu AMI (micro).

Here's how I've formatted and mounted the volume (8 GB):

```
sudo mkfs.ext4 /dev/xvdf
mkdir -m 000 /data
echo "/dev/xvdf /data auto noatime 0 0" | sudo tee -a /etc/fstab
sudo mount /data
```

Comment: What is the size of the attached EBS volume, also have you formatted and mounted it properly ??

Comment: I've edited the question to add this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like I fat-fingered a file named `ln` in `/data/mysql/lib/mysql/`. This file was symlinked to itself, which apparently created an infinite loop of symlinks, hence the error `'Too many levels of symbolic links'`.

But I don't understand why MySQL would try to access this file in the first place.

Answer (score 0):

Here are the few heads up I can give,
1) Remove the symlink and provide the absolute path, may be because of the syslink its throwing out errors.If it doesnt work uninstall the mysql db and reinstall it again and make sure you provide the path of the attached volume.One more thing did you stop the mysql server before moving all your files to new volume?? Try restarting mysql server once,hope it helps!!!

Answer (score 0):

The procedure below works for me every time.

`#mkfs.ext4 /dev/xvdf`

`#mkdir /mnt/data`

`#mount /dev/xvdf /mnt/data`

`#/etc/init.d/mysql stop`

Edit `/etc/mysql/my.cnf` file and look for the entry for “datadir”, and change the path (which should be "/var/lib/mysql") to the new data directory (/mnt/data).

`#/etc/init.d/mysql restart`

Answer (score 0):

Every time I see questions like this, I would ask "why don't you use RDS"?

http://aws.amazon.com/rds/

It's exactly like issues like this that you want to use cloud based service - so that you don't need to worry anything about administrating/configuring hardware,database,etc.

Comment: RDS also has downsides.. You don't have the super privilege, you are limited in changing the server settings, automated or manual scaling out to more read slaves takes plenty of (down)time, same for snapshot recovery and finally it is more expensive. We have replaced all RDS instances by self-managed EC2 servers and I cannot recommend RDS for any advanced project

Comment: (1) RDS is costly for small projects. (2) I want to improve my sysadmin skills. I'd rather fix this problem instead of ignoring it by switching to a different service.